# $A,B,X,Y$ are four invertible matrices. If $AYB=XY$, can I express matrix $X$ in the terms of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$A,B,X,Y$ are four invertible matrices. If $AYB=XY$, can I express matrix $X$ in the terms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Your question is a little different from the title.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in general unless you assume something stronger about the matrices. E.g. [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices).

Naturally, if you are okay with $Y$ and its inverse appearing in the product, $AYBY^{-1}=X$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $AYBY^{-1}=XYY^{-1}=X$, but in general you cannot write $X$ only in terms of $A$ and $B$. For example, for $A=I$, $B=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $Y=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\0&x\end{matrix}\right)$ (just picking some random values), $$X=AYBY^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}2&-x^{-1}\\x&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

which is clearly dependent on $x$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, that is not what I want. I want to express the matrix X ONLY in the form of A and B.

Comment: @PeterYu  I have proven exactly that it is impossible to do as you ask. If there were some expression $X=f(A,B)$ which does not depend on $Y$, then $X$ could not have an $x$ in it in my example. Yet it does, which indicates that the dependence on $Y$ is inextricable.